# Drupal Style Configuration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I searched a lot on the internet to see a general answer about customizing the view of Drupal main components(if I can call them components) like Fields, Blocks, Views...

I know CSS can work and ... but I need to know if I find the html elements in which CSS files I should put the configurations.

I know it depends on theme css files. But which ones should be used for each of those components?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know where are the html of your drupal to change it? or where are the css files?

Comment: For sure :)

I'm just confused how I can customize the appearance in Drupal! If you can give me a website-link about it , it would be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: Check my response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the html files are in the theme folder.
If you are using Omega (for example), in the sites/all/themes/omega, you have the .tpl files, that Drupal uses to render the content.

For example, the file **block.tpl.php** is the file that contains the skeleton of any block in your site. Of course the content of the blocks is in the block page (not in the tpl).

The node content is in the **node.tpl.php** file, you may override the skeleton of any content type if you create other tpl file, for example node--article.tpl.php (for article content type).

You have **html.tpl.php** and **page.tpl.php** to customize the skeleton of your page. If you add some html in this files, this content appears in all pages.

Maybe this article helps you: https://www.drupal.org/node/171194

Regards.